# YAML scalar with double %

Tags: symfony

I am trying to connect to a database with symfony3 but the problem is when I put the password in parameters.yml, I get this error:

database_password: xx%xxxxx%x

> You have requested a non-existent parameter "xxxxx".

I tried with

- database_password: "xx%xxxxx%x"
- database_password: 'xx%xxxxx%x'
- database_password: "xx\%xxxxx\%x"

I always have the same problem

Comment: The first two things that you tried are exactly the same as the original YAML, as there are no special characters the quoting is not necessary. So trying that was a waste of time. The third is invalid YAML and should throw an error, as `%` is not an escapable character in a double quoted scalar.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape percentage signs by putting two:

```
database_password: 'xx%%xxxxx%%x'
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html#parameters-in-configuration-files for more info.

Note: technically the quotes are unnecessary in this example, but if a `%`-sign appears at the start of the scalar, the scalar must be quoted.

Comment: Thanx for your help

Comment: Why make things complicated by adding unnecessary quotes around the scalar?

Comment: @Anthon '%' is an indicator character in the YAML syntax, therefor you should quote values that contain them, see http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2772075

Comment: @Gerry I know that `%` is the directive indicator, and, in the rule you point to, there is nothing that warrant your "therefor[e]". `%` has special meaning at the beginning of a line **only**. Per rule [126] (ns-plain-first(c)) of the specification it is clear that it only is not allowed at the **beginning** of a scalar (whether that it is a value or not is irrelevant).

Comment: @Anthon, yet I am the one over-complicating things? :) I assume people trying to escape %-literals at the start of a scalar might also be interested in this answer, since the position of the % is not really important in the context of the question.